# Problem with creating Python 3.6 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python3, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 has Python 3.6 and Python 3.8 support. Command `python3 -m venv my_venv` creates virtual environment with python 3.8 and it works as expected.

However, trying `python3.6 -m venv my_venv3.6` does not work. The response I get is `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named venv`.

I tried using `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 my_venv3.6`, which results in:

```
RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.6 with code 1 err: ...
```

I also tried installing `sudo apt install python3.6-venv` which results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.6-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.6-venv' has no installation candidate
```

Note that running `python3.6` starts interactive python prompt with Python 3.6.9. I can also run scripts this way, so it seems that Python 3.6 is indeed usable on my system.

How can I start Python 3.6 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I'm unable to add a comment to the previous answer (new user, not enough reputation points), but 20.04 does not have `python-virtualenv`. Rather, you will need to use: ```
apt-get install python3-virtualenv
``` Then to create your virtual environment for Python 3.6 you can simply do:
```
virtualenv -p python3.6 env
``` Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The venv package is not included in the regular python package. It has to be installed for each Python versions, e.g. `sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 ships with default Python 3.8. So first you will need to install Python 3.6.

1. Install python 3.6:

   ```bsh
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python3.6
   ```
2. If the `virtualenv` package is not installed, run:

   ```bsh
   apt-get update
   apt-get install python3-virtualenv
   ```
3. Create a virtual environment:

   ```bsh
   virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv
   ```

Comment: Followed the process but after step 2 I'm getting error **E: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate**

Comment: Thanks @AnupRaj. I have updated the answer with latest command to install virtualenv in step2. You can follow these steps again.

Comment: I had no luck either after creating even virtual environment.

Comment: @JiteshSojitra Did you activate the virtual environment you created?. If not than use command **source ./venv/bin/activate**.

Comment: As an alternative to step 2 & 3, you could `sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv` and `python3.6 -m venv mypy36venv`. More information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: don't forget to reinstall pip for 3.6 as well `sudo apt install python3-pip -y`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
pyenv install 3.6.13
pyenv global 3.6.13
pyenv local 3.6.13
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv_ok
```