# Python virtualenv problem after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: 20.04, python3, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I updated my system to Ubuntu 20.04

I already had `Python 3.6.7` running with `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` for my python virtual environment.

After the update

I am able to check get the list of virtual environments those I have already created, but when I tried creating a new virtual environment `mkvirtualenv -p python newenv`

I get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py)
```

Then I checked the python version after update it was `Python 3.8.5`

I checked for `main` inside `virtualenv` that the `Python 3.8.5`

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from virtualenv import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py)
>>>
```

I tried installing `virtualenv` and `virtualwrapper` for `Python 3.8.5`

`python -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

since my default `Python` version is `3.8.5` after the update

even after installing I get the same message `ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv'`

I found this post [Problem with creating Python 3.6 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231543/problem-with-creating-python-3-6-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Installed `Python 3.6.7` as suggested the most popular answer

```
cd opt
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/Python-3.6.7.tgz
sudo tar -xvf Python-3.6.7.tgz
cd Python-3.6.7

make clean

sudo ./configure

sudo make
sudo make install
```

updated my `bashrc`

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenv

# Virtual Environment Wrapper
source /home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

For VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

For VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV

```
sudo find / -name "virtualenv"
/home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenv
```

For virtualenvwrapper.sh

```
sudo find / -name "virtualenvwrapper.sh"
/home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

`source ~/.bashrc`

`Python3 -V` displays `Python 3.6.7`

`Python -V` displays `Python 3.8.5`

Installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` for `Python 3.6.7`, using `Python3 -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

Now I tried creating a virtualenv using `Python 3.6.7`

`mkvirtualenv -p python3 newenv`

I get back the same message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abcd/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py)
```

When I went inside the `Python 3.6.7` and `Python 3.8.5` check for `from virtualenv import main`

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from virtualenv import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py)
>>>
```

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, May 26 2021, 09:24:09) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from virtualenv import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
>>>
```

Whats is the solution, here?

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall the whole environment? I came across the same problem with updating python and I needed to create a new environment. Did you tried to update your alternatives like desribed here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux ?